# Spark Streaming Receiver particularly slow on YARN

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, spark-streaming

The following Spark Streaming code makes a `DStream[Int]` which contains a stream of random integers.

```
// these lines can be copy-pasted to `spark-shell`
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.Receiver

import scala.util.Random

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Duration(1000))

val numbers = ssc.receiverStream(new Receiver[Int](StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY) {
  lazy val thread = new Thread() {
    override def run(): Unit = {
      while(!isInterrupted) {
        store(Random.nextInt())
        Thread.sleep(100)
      }
    }
  }

  override def onStart(): Unit = thread.start()
  override def onStop(): Unit = thread.interrupt()
})

numbers.print()

ssc.start()
```

On local mode or standalone cluster mode, this code works exactly as intended, with <50ms delay. However, on YARN, (run using `HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf spark-shell --master yarn-client`) the delay increases linearly with time, making the streaming application unusable, like this:

[image: Spark UI]

There should be `print()` output every second, but on YARN the output is produced in about every 5 seconds, making the linear delay increase.

I'm running spark 1.2.0 on yarn 2.5.0-cdh5.3.0, which allocated 2 executors with -Xmx1024m each. If anyone is interested, [these](http://pastebin.com/6RbZ4d6X) are the stdout log.

Does anyone aware of this issue or has any clues? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I noticed that this issue goes away when using replication level >= 2, such as `MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2` but I don't understand why.